# Why the quotient of the circumference over the diameter is an irrational number?

Tags: geometry, pi

In the decimal system, circumference / diameter = 3.14159265359...

But, for example, in binary, that ratio is 11.00100100001111110111...
Or in hexadecimal, 3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E037073...

We also obtain an irrational number, independent of the numeric system that we use.

Has something to do with the fact that we use decimal system, or with the dimensions of the given space?
Could it be otherwise, with another set of rules or number of spatial dimensions? (Obtain an exact number)

Comment: The rationality of a number does neither depend on its representation nor on the base-system it is displayed. "why" $\pi$ turned out to be irrational , even transcendental , is a philosophical question. One might argue that "almost every real number" is transcendental, but this is not a satisfying answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Peter Thanks!
But _is it_ a philosophical question? Has it in fact been proven that is not a geometrical result given the properties of the given space?

Comment: Well, if we take the ratio of the length of a diagonal in a square to the length of this square, we know that the result is algebraic irrational , namely $\sqrt{2}$. This follows from the Pythagorean theorem, but "why" does this theorem hold ? I have no clue, maybe someone knows the "reason".

Comment: @Peter I agree. A proof is not a reason, however much people like to think it is. Yes, it is proven that $\pi$ is irrational, but there isn't any particular, fundamental, underlying _reason_ for it. There are just ways of demonstrating that it is true. (There do exist reasons why one might _expect_ a certain statement to be true, and some of those could be expanded into a full proof, but that's different.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Peter

Comment: @Arthur I understand. Given the present knowledge, it seems a fundamental property of the geometry of the universe that we live in, much like Planck's constant, which we currently don't have a reason for it having its value. (Which given that is an experimental value, we can't say that is irrational, but we don't know why it has that value)

Comment: @Arthur Exactly , and sometimes there are huge surprises , witness the Godstein sequences , utterly counterintuitive , or that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes of the form Graham's number$\cdot n+2$ , $n$ positive integer , diverges is extremely counterintuitive as well. But we know this from Dirichlet who did not only prove that there are infinite many such primes.

Answer (score 3):

The representation is irrelevant since the repeating pattern forces the number to be rational. Say we have a number that repeats eventually in base $n$ called $r$ and say the digits repeat after $k$ digits.  In general there will be an integer portion, a non-repeating portion after the decimal, and then the repeating portion. The first step is to find some appropriate power of $n$ so that the repeating pattern starts at the decimal point. So say I have $r=0.124737373...$ in base $8$ I would multiply by $8^3$ so that $8^3s=124.737373....$ and from here we then multiply by $n^k$ to move the pattern to match up with itself again. So in our running example we would have that $8^28^3s=8^5s = 12473.737373...$ and now we subtract to remove the portion after the decimal place so in our example we take $8^5s -8^3s = 12473.737373... - 124.737373... = 12349$ and so we have that $(8^5-8^3)s = 12349$ Simply noticing that $8 = 10$ base $8$ this gives us $(10000-1000)s = 1700s=12349$ and so solving for $s$ we recover $s=12349/1700$. This works in every base just like it does in base 10. It's a property of the notation itself rather than the base.